# Replacing Base64 - Possibility of Unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode, base64

Base64 ( 2^6 ) uses a subset of characters, usually

```
a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / , +
```

It does not use all 128 defined in ASCII because non-printable characters can not be used.

However, each character takes up 2^8 space.

This results in 33% ( 4/3 ) wasted space.

why can't a subset of UTF-8 be used which has 256 printable characters.  Hence instead of the limited  subset listed above, the richness of UTF could be used to fill all 8 bits.

This way there would be no loss.

Comment: So you want to create an encoding for bytes in which each byte is represented by a code unit that's one byte large?

Comment: well, yea, if it takes up 8 bits, why not find a way to use all 8 bits.

Comment: Try this function (but don't reuse it, I've patented it): `uint8_t compressed_encode_byte(uint8_t input) { return input; }`. Guaranteed to be 100% space-efficient.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_pair_encoding

Comment: why not do something simple like find 256 consecutive printable characters in unicode and map them to a byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why can't a subset of UTF-8 be used which has 256 printable
>   characters. Hence instead of the limited subset listed above, the
>   richness of UTF could be used to fill all 8 bits.

Suppose you used a subset that contained the 94 non-space printable characters from the ASCII range (encoded in UTF-8 as 1 byte each) and 162 characters from somewhere in the U+0080 to U+07FF range (encoded in UTF-8 as 2 bytes each).  Assuming a uniform distribution of values, you'd need an average of 1.6328125 bytes of text per byte of data, which is less efficient than Base64's 1.3333333.

Comment: The point is we have 256 printable characters now, unlike the days of ASCII, we need to translate 256 of them to an 8 bit system.

Answer (score 3):

Base64 is used to encode arbitrary 8bit data in systems that do not support 8bit data, like email and XML. Its use of 7bit ASCII characters is deliberate, so it can pass through 7bit systems, like email. But it is not the only data encoding format in the world, though.  yEnc, for example, tends to have slightly better compression than base64.  And if your data is mostly ASCII-compatible, Quoted-Printable is almost 1-to-1.

UTFs are meant for encoding Unicode text, not arbitrary binary data. Period.

Pick an encoding that is appropriate for the data and usage. Don't just try coherse an encoding into doing something it is not meant to do.

Comment: "systems that don't support 8 bit data" - exactly why it is ridiculous that this is used in web.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 uses 2 bytes for characters 128-255, so would use 16 bits to store 8 bits (50% efficiency) instead of using 8 bits to store 6 bits (75% efficiency)

Comment: ...UTF-8 is variable width ( 1 - 4 bytes )...and can also be used in such a way that only 1 byte is used.

Comment: UTF-8 uses 1 byte for values 0-127, 2 bytes for values 128-2047, etc. If you're using 1 byte for values 128-255 you're not using UTF-8. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8